# Which of these is more efficient while reusing a variable in a loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Just wondering which one makes more sense for the declaration of 'a' and 'pushRes' and why you would choose one over the other in terms of memory, scope etc? I am removing the try/catch blocks for simplicity.

```
const pushRes=[];
for (..){
    const a = await myFunc(i);
    pushRes.push(a);
}
```

or

```
let a;
let pushRes=[];
for (...){
a = await myFunc(i);
pushRes.push(a);
}
```

Comment: This is more a question to be asked on code.review, since there's not a problem found here.

Comment: @Steven There's not even working code which is one requirement for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You are right @Steven. There isn't a problem - just asking a general question on why one approach may be better than the other specifically as it relates to re-declaring the same variable as a "const" inside the loop vs using let.

Comment: I just updated the title and body. Hope it makes it clearer now.

Comment: Efficient in terms of what? Any measurable performance difference will be insignificant to the overhead that `await` introduces.

Comment: Efficient in terms of scoping and memory utilization

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to declare it, neither to use await. Just add the func directly as a param for ur other function. It wont trigger the function, till myFunc returns a value.

```
const pushRes=[];
for (..){
    pushRes.push(myFunc(i));
}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at what `await` does

Answer (score 0):

Any possible performance difference will be insignificant compared to what else is going in the code.

You should go for readability. Declaring a variable outside of the loop seems to express that you need that variable outside of the loop. If not then you are just introducing unnecessary complexity. Declare variables as close as possible to where they are used.